# How to get testStep responseAsXml in groovyScript

Tags: groovy, soapui

Concerning soapUI and groovy, I'm trying to get assertion (working) and response both in XML into a variable. I get the error

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep.getResponseAsXml() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] error at line: 6
```

I have tried adding `import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep` but still cant figure it. I did another attempt with message exchange, also to no avail - from what i understand you can't actually use messageExchange in this particular instance

```
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.Assertable.AssertionStatus
def TestCase = testRunner.getTestCase()
def StepList = TestCase.getTestStepList()

StepList.each
{
    if(it.metaClass.hasProperty(it,'assertionStatus'))
    {
        if(it.assertionStatus == AssertionStatus.FAILED)
        {
            def ass = it.getAssertableContentAsXml()
            def res = it.getResponseContentAsXml()

            log.error "${it.name} " + "${it.assertionStatus}"
            log.info ass + res

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As the exception says quite plainly.  The class [`WsdlTestRequestStep`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/WsdlTestRequestStep.html) doesn't have a method `getResponseContentAsXml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the response from [`com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/WsdlTestRequestStep.html), a possible way is first get the testStep from this class using [`getTestStep()`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/WsdlTestRequestStep.html#getTestStep()) method.

This method returns a object of class [`com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestStep`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/testsuite/TestStep.html%60), from this object you can get the testSteps properties like request, response, endpoint... using [`getPropertyValue(java.lang.string)`](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/TestPropertyHolder.html#getPropertyValue(java.lang.String)) method.

So in your case to get the response use:

`def res = it.getTestStep().getPropertyValue('Response')`

instead of:

`def res = it.getResponseContentAsXml()`

As @tim_yates comments the exception description in this case it's pretty clear, so please take a look at the [SOAPUI api](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/) and at the links provided in the answer for the next time `:)`.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Going through that api isn't all that simple for a n00b like myself, but I should've seen that. Thanks @tim_yates and albciff

Comment: @MistaWizard right probably it isn't simple, and also unfortunately the groovy editor in soapui without code assist isn't the better place to start. nice to help you `:)`.